# Why Linq "where" expression after Select gets evaluated locally when created through a generic method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing Specification pattern with generics and trying to dynamically apply criteria to projected simple (unmapped) versions of mapped entities. In general, it works fine, but Linq evaluates the expression locally as soon as I add `Select` and apply `Where` after it.

The exact same Linq expression yields correct SQL query, if I build it as a local variable and pass to the same `Where`.

Here's the simplified relevant code snippet:

```
public interface ISomeable
{
    string Some { get; set; }
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetCriteria<T>() where T : class, ISomeable
    {  return e => (e.Some == "Hello"); }


...

Expression<Func<MySimpleEntity, bool>> someCriteria = e => (e.Some == "Hello");
Expression<Func<MySimpleEntity, bool>> someCriteria2 = GetCriteria<MySimpleEntity>();

var query = db.Entities
       .Select(s => new MySimpleEntity { Id = s.Id, Some = s.Some });
// if this Select is removed and MySimpleEntity in both expressions replaced with MyFullEntity, 
// the issue disappears

// this succeeds
var filteredQueryResults = query.Where(someCriteria).ToList();

// at this point, someCriteria2 is set to the same e => (e.Some == "Hello");

// this fails: why is it evaluated locally and not in SQL? <-----
filteredQueryResults = query.Where(someCriteria2).ToList();

// results in a warning:

                /*
                 * 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: 
                 * The LINQ expression 'where (new MySimpleEntity() {Id = [s].Id, Some = [s].Some}.Some == "Hello")' 
                 * could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. 
                 */
```

**How do I make it generate correct SQL instead of local evaluation for `someCriteria2`?**

I suspect I need some kind of casting, but not sure where. Both `someCriteria` and `someCriteria2` look exactly the same in the debugger, so I have no idea why Linq is treating them differently.

I have created a minimal .Net Core Console app to reproduce the case. The full gist is here:

https://gist.github.com/progmars/eeec32a533dbd2e1f85e551db1bc53f8

NuGet dependencies:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6"
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0"
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0"

Some explanations:

It is not related to the fact that the same query is executed twice. If I comment out the first `query.Where(someCriteria).ToList()` the second call with `someCriteria2` still fails to generate valid SQL. However, if I replace `someCriteria2` with `someCriteria` for the second query and let it run, I get two exact valid SQL queries in the console. So, it's all related to generics of `someCriteria2` and `Select` projection - for some reason, Linq doesn't treat both variables the same, even if compiler (and debugger watch) thinks they are the same exact type.

Comment: I see that in the second expression the member part of `e.Some` is declared on `ISomable`, whereas in the first expression this is `MySimpleEntity`. However, I don't understand why this makes a difference with projected entities only. It seems that query translation with projections follows a different path than with entities EF materialized itself, probably because the projection must be translated back to the entity, even when the projected type is an entity type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is similar to [The LINQ expression could not be translated for base property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295009/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-for-base-property/55296106#55296106) and [How to use inherited properties in EF Core expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805830/how-to-use-inherited-properties-in-ef-core-expressions/40807375#40807375), but in this case both the `DeclaringType` and `ReflectedType` of the `MemberInfo` point to `ISomeable` interface rather than the actual class.

Again this somehow is confusing EF Core in the `Select` scenario. I've checked the latest EF Core 3.0 preview and it also doesn't work. You might consider posting it to their issue tracker.

The only workaround I could offer so far is to postprocess the expression with custom `ExpressionVisitor` and bind the  member accessors to the actual class. Something like this:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression<T> FixMemberAccess<T>(this Expression<T> source)
    {
        var body = new MemberAccessFixer().Visit(source.Body);
        if (body == source.Body) return source;
        return source.Update(body, source.Parameters);
    }

    class MemberAccessFixer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Expression != null && node.Expression.Type != node.Member.DeclaringType)
            {
                var member = node.Expression.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single();
                if (member.ReflectedType != member.DeclaringType)
                    member = member.DeclaringType.GetMember(member.Name).Single();
                return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(node.Expression, member);
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```

and now

```
var someCriteria2 = GetCriteria<MySimpleEntity>().FixMemberAccess();
```

will produce the exact expression as the working compile time `someCriteria` expression and no client evaluation.

Note: You still need the `class` constraint in order to avoid the casting issue from your previous question and to make this workaround work.

Comment: An alternative is to build the correct expression directly in `GetCriteria<T>()`.

Comment: @GertArnold Valid point. But at this point for me it will be simpler to add this DeclaringType re-mapper than build new Expression trees manually.

Comment: normally this works via interface too, if a entity is implementing an interface, Expression of that interface type works

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I guess by "normally" you mean LINQ to Objects where everything that compiles also works because it's simply compiled to delegate? `IQueryable` translators are different thing. And with EF Core this specifically doesn't work.

Comment: @Gert That's true, but I'm assuming they don't want to build expressions manually. Also if you look at the linked posts, even there are some unusual traps to be avoided.

Comment: @IvanStoev no i am talking about `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: @IvanStoev tested on EF core 2.2.6 and seems to be working perfectly fine

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Try the OP repro. The problem is in `Where` *after* projection (`Select`).

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you, FixMemberAccess  fixed the issue for interfaces. But I just tried a slightly different scenario using `public class SomeableBase : ISomeable`  and `public class MySimpleEntity : SomeableBase`; I removed the field `Some` from `MySimpleEntity` - it's inherited now. Now FixMemberAccess doesn't quite work - it converts ISomeable member access to SomeableBase instead of MySimpleEntity because PropertyOrField finds Some on SomeableBase.  Is there any way to adjust FixMemberAccess  to map also inherited fields to the expression type?

Comment: @JustAMartin Omg, now that's the issue from the other posts. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works perfectly. I also kept the `class` constraint as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is

```
GetCriteria<MySimpleEntity>();
```

`linq` cannot translate that directly to `sql` or doesn't have a direct translation. If you want to use it. Execute `ToList()` then add `.Where(someCriteria2).ToList();`. In watcher it sees/evaluate it as the same. But in the query itself, generating the sql doesn't seem to work that way.

I have also experienced that in my `DateTime` extension methods even in converting it to `string` in my `Where` i had to execute it outside of my `linq` query and add it

`var dateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.ExtensionMethod()`;

`...Where(x => x.Date >= dateUtc`)

or I execute `FirstorDefault, First, ToList()` first before my `select` and/or `where`

Comment: If I execute `.ToList()` before applying `.Where(someCriteria2)`, this would essentially be the same as letting Linq itself evaluate it locally; which is highly undesirable (reading a table with thousands of records and then applying Where criteria in memory).

Comment: @JustAMartin But some methods, functions, extensions cannot be directly translated by linq to sql, i dont know why it does but i have encountered it.

Comment: Yes, it seems, EF Core lacks some functionality. This time, the query itself is a simple `string == "Value"` but somehow Linq cannot deal with it when it's constructed on an interface or base class entity.

Comment: Even in my last project using EF 6, i have encountered that. That is why in my projects, if i do conversions, extensions or anything that i feel cannot be directly translated, i declare it outside of the `linq` query into a variable then i put the created variable in my where to match it with the property

Comment: @JustAMartin hope my answer has helped you.