# Casting generic type to build a valid Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting

I got stuck with attempt of generic casting or building a LINQ expression that could be casted to the required generic type `T`.

Here is the failing example:

```
public override void PreprocessFilters<T>(ISpecification<T> specification)
{
    if (typeof(ICompanyLimitedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        var companyId = 101; // not relevant, retrieving company ID here

        // and now I need to call the method AddCriteria on the specification
        // as it were ISpecification<ICompanyLimitedEntity>
        // which it should be because at this point I know 
        // that T is ICompanyLimitedEntity
        var cle = specification as ISpecification<ICompanyLimitedEntity>;
        //                      ^-- but of course this conversion won't work, cle is null

        // what should I do now?

        // I need to call it like this:
        cle.AddCriteria(e => e.CompanyId == null ||
            e.CompanyId == 0 || e.CompanyId == companyId);
        // BTW, AddCriteria receives Expression<Func<T, bool>> as an argument

        // tried nasty casts inside of the expression - this doesn't throw NullReference
        // but it doesn't translate to SQL either - gets evaluated locally in memory, which is bad
        specification.AddCriteria(e => ((ICompanyLimitedEntity)e).CompanyId == null ||
            ((ICompanyLimitedEntity)e).CompanyId == 0 || 
            ((ICompanyLimitedEntity)e).CompanyId == companyId);

        // this one also doesn't work

        Expression<Func<ICompanyLimitedEntity, bool>> lex = e => e.CompanyId == null ||
                    e.CompanyId == 0 || e.CompanyId == companyId;

        // it's null again -----------v
        specification.AndCriteria(lex as Expression<Func<T, bool>>);
    }
}
```

**Is there any way to cast T or build a Linq expression that would treat `T` as `ICompanyLimitedEntity` and execute the query on the SQL server?**

Comment: Have you tried `public override void PrerocessFilters<T>(ISpecification<T> specification) where T : ICompanyLimitedEntity`? Which also makes the `IsAssignableFrom` check redundant.

Comment: @Funk It would be the best solution, if the T always was ICompanyLimitedEntity, but it isn't guaranteed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can build the desired expression.

First you create compile time expression with interface type parameter

```
Expression<Func<ICompanyLimitedEntity, bool>> exprI = e => e.CompanyId == null ||
            e.CompanyId == 0 || e.CompanyId == companyId;
```

then replace the parameter inside the body with a new parameter of type `T` and use the modified expression as a body for the new lambda expression:

```
var parameterT = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
var bodyT = exprI.Body.ReplaceParameter(exprI.Parameters[0], parameterT);
var exprT = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(bodyT, parameterT);
```

where `ReplaceParameter` is the typical `ExpressionVisitor` based helper for replacing parameter with another expression:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Source ? Target : node;
    }
}
```

Note that you'll still need the member access expression fixer from [Why Linq "where" expression after Select gets evaluated locally when created through a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389115/why-linq-where-expression-after-select-gets-evaluated-locally-when-created-thr)