# Basic Type-Generic EF Core 3.1 -> SQL Server Where Clause cannot be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-core-3.0

Using EF Core, no matter what I do, I am unable to get the lambda in the `Where` statement to correctly evaluate to SQL.  I have a basic generic LINQ query  that takes an argument of type `T where T :class, ICommonModel`, this translates via a Repository that returns a `IQueryable of TCommon where TCommon : :class, ICommonModel`, but under the hood is using `TData where TData : :class, IDataModel`. I'm not sure exactly where the failure is, but no matter what it seems like it can't handle anything in the `Where` clause.

Here's the method with the Where clause.

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
            => await this.repository.Read().Where(r => ids.Contains(r.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

Here's an even simpler statement that still fails, so it's not related to the `Contains` call as Initially thought.

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
            => await this.repository.Read().Where(r => r.Id.ToString().Contains("0")).ToListAsync();
```

The error I get is

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Person>
    .Where(p => new Person{ 
        ContactNumber = p.ContactNumber, 
        Email = p.Email, 
        FullName = p.FullName, 
        Id = p.Id 
    }
    .Id.ToString().Contains("0"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Here's the Repo method

```
        public virtual IQueryable<TCommon> Read()
            => this.Context.Set<TData>().ProjectTo<TCommon>(this.Mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

The interface for both methods are identical.

```
    public interface IDataModel {

        Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
...
    public interface ICommonModel {
        Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `class` constraint? It usually helps.

Comment: Just tried to add it as a constraint on every interface and implementation and still get the same results.  `public abstract class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class, ICommonModel`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, reproduced it. Seems to be broken in 3.0/3.1, unfortunately all you can do is to report it to their GitHub issue tracker (if it's not already there) and wait/hope to be fixed soon.

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389115/why-linq-where-expression-after-select-gets-evaluated-locally-when-created-thr/57392731#57392731. Same workaround works. Can be extended with custom `IQeryable<T>` extension method and applied at query level.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev - I put an issue with the the team. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19679